# ExtJS - hbox layout new row

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this piece of code:

```
var dashboardPanel1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    collapsible: true,
    margin: '0 0 50 0',

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
        flex: 1,
        border: 0
    },

    title: '<span class="mytitle" id="keySettings"><a href="#" style="">Key settings</a></span>',

    items: [{
        html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',
        flex: 0.2

    }, {
        html: 'Your key is active'
    }, {
        html: 'Expiring date: 27.04.2018'
    }, {
        html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',
        flex: 0.2

    }, {
        html: 'Your key is inactive'
    }, {
        html: 'Expiring date: 27.03.2018'
    }]
});
```

It is displaying a panel with some content.
But how can I display this "Your key is inactive" and expiring date in a new row.

If I choose `table` layout I cannot get the content `streched` (maximum width). So I have to use `hbox`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You want it to be grid, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always nest boxes. Depending on your requirements, either use vboxes inside a hbox:

[image]

or even hboxes inside a vbox inside a hbox:

[image]

Or maybe you can use a table layout and add a width to the [`tableAttrs`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.layout.container.Table.html#cfg-tableAttrs) to make it stretch:

```
layout: 'table',
tableAttrs: {
    width: '100%'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this, its not a great answer either. It assumes this layout is static and not changing which I don't think is what you are looking for. But for fun here is an example I came up with that should emulate what your looking for.

```js
var dashboardPanel1 = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      collapsible: true,
      margin: '0 0 50 0',
      flex: 1,
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
      },
      defaults: {
        flex: 0.5,
        border: 0
      },
      title: '<span class="mytitle" id="keySettings"><a href="#" style="">Key settings</a></span>',

      items: [{
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: {
            'type': 'vbox'
          },
          items: [{
              xtype: 'box',
              html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',
            },
            {
              xtype: 'container',
              layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
              },
              defaults: {
                flex: 0.5
              },
              items: [{
                  xtype: 'box',
                  html: 'Your key is active'
                },
                {
                  xtype: 'box',
                  html: 'Expiring date: 27.04.2018'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: {
            'type': 'vbox'
          },
          items: [{
              xtype: 'box',
              html: '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/n7gOYrE.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px">',
            },
            {
              xtype: 'container',
              layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
              },
              defaults: {
                flex: 0.5
              },
              items: [{
                  xtype: 'box',
                  html: 'Your key is active'
                },
                {
                  xtype: 'box',
                  html: 'Expiring date: 27.04.2018'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      });
```